# Flutter button won't change text when clicked

Tags: flutter

So, strangely...

I have two screens. A Register screen and a Login screen.
The Login screen maintains the same logic as the Register screen for the button feature. Meaning, when I click the login screen button for `Login`, the button gets disabled (from being clicked more than once) and its text changes to `Logging In...`

Is there something I am missing in my logic for the Register screen?
Below is the module for the Register screen:

```
class RegisterEmailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterEmailScreenState createState() => _RegisterEmailScreenState();
}

class _RegisterEmailScreenState extends State<RegisterEmailScreen> {
  bool _signUpButtonClicked = false;
  String _signUpButtonMessage = 'Register';

  // Some form code
  child: OutlinedButton(
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 45.h),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          _signUpButtonMessage,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.ssp),
                        ),
                        onPressed: _signUpButtonClicked
                            ? null
                            : () async {
                                if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  return;
                                }
                                setState(() => {
                                      _signUpButtonMessage: 'Registering...',
                                      _signUpButtonClicked: true,
                                    });
                                var name = _nameController.text;
                                var username = _usernameController.text;
                                var password = _passwordController.text;
                                var email = _emailController.text;
                                print('Registering with: ' + username);

                                var signUpReponse = await attemptRegistration(
                                    nome,
                                    username,
                                    password,
                                    email);
                                setState(() => {
                                      _signUpButtonClicked: false,
                                      _signUpButtonMessage: 'Register',
                                    });
                                // Some more code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
It was a simple syntax mistake. Notice that the posting question has `_signUpButtonClicked : false` (and other variables in `setState()`. It was supposed to be an `=` operator for all.

The code below simply changes all 4 instances of the mistake above:

```
class RegisterEmailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterEmailScreenState createState() => _RegisterEmailScreenState();
}

class _RegisterEmailScreenState extends State<RegisterEmailScreen> {
  bool _signUpButtonClicked = false;
  String _signUpButtonMessage = 'Register';

  // Some form code
  child: OutlinedButton(
                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 45.h),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          _signUpButtonMessage,
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.ssp),
                        ),
                        onPressed: _signUpButtonClicked
                            ? null
                            : () async {
                                if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  return;
                                }
                                setState(() => {
                                      _signUpButtonMessage = 'Registering...',
                                      _signUpButtonClicked = true,
                                    });
                                var name = _nameController.text;
                                var username = _usernameController.text;
                                var password = _passwordController.text;
                                var email = _emailController.text;
                                print('Registering with: ' + username);

                                var signUpReponse = await attemptRegistration(
                                    nome,
                                    username,
                                    password,
                                    email);
                                setState(() => {
                                      _signUpButtonClicked = false,
                                      _signUpButtonMessage = 'Register',
                                    });
                                // Some more code
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistakenly return values in the `setState` method using arrow function. You should set the values like below

```
onPressed: _signUpButtonClicked
                            ? null
                            : () async {
                                if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  return;
                                }
                                setState(() {
                                      _signUpButtonMessage= 'Registering...';
                                      _signUpButtonClicked= true;
                                    });
                                var name = _nameController.text;
                                var username = _usernameController.text;
                                var password = _passwordController.text;
                                var email = _emailController.text;
                                print('Registering with: ' + username);

                                var signUpReponse = await attemptRegistration(
                                    nome,
                                    username,
                                    password,
                                    email);
                                setState(() {
                                      _signUpButtonClicked= false;
                                      _signUpButtonMessage='Register';
                                    });
                                // Some more code
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not it.

I `setState(() {})` in another occasion, but on this one it does not work.

VSCode helper below replies:
The label '_signUpButtonClicked' isn't used.
Try removing the label, or using it in either a 'break' or 'continue' statement.dart(unused_label)

Comment: sorry to hear that. for me its working. check this on dartpad https://dartpad.dev/?id=bd4b3f7e6c8c08c1b9ec30c42e2b9a4e&null_safety=true

Comment: arrow function doesn't update the fields. check field values after arrow function.

Comment: Actually it does. I was simply changing from `=` to `:` on both `setState()`. Thanks for your help, rosh! I hope you learned something new as well.